# How to get all items and their value by mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I have three mysql tables.

**Table-01: table_item**

In this table, all items with their corresponding ids are stored. Items are categorized in two categories. One is writing category (catid-1) and another is clothing category (catid-2).

```
---------------------------------------------
| id | catname |  catid | itemid | itemname |
---------------------------------------------
║  1 ║ writing ║    1   ║   1    ║   Pen    ║
║  2 ║ writing ║    1   ║   2    ║  Pencil  ║
║  3 ║ writing ║    1   ║   3    ║ Sharpner ║
║  4 ║clothing ║    2   ║   4    ║   Pant   ║
║  5 ║clothing ║    2   ║   5    ║   shirt  ║
║  6 ║clothing ║    2   ║   6    ║   coat   ║
║  7 ║clothing ║    2   ║   7    ║   Tie    ║
---------------------------------------------
```

**Table-02: bid_item**

Each year bid/tender is called for purchasing selective items from the above item table (table_item). So in this table, selected items, those are selected for bid/tender, are stored per year basis.

```
----------------------
║ id ║ itemid ║ year ║
----------------------
║  1 ║   1    ║ 2015 ║
║  2 ║   2    ║ 2015 ║
║  3 ║   3    ║ 2015 ║
║  4 ║   4    ║ 2015 ║
║  5 ║   5    ║ 2015 ║
║  6 ║   6    ║ 2015 ║
║  7 ║   1    ║ 2016 ║
║  8 ║   2    ║ 2016 ║
║  9 ║   3    ║ 2016 ║
║ 10 ║   4    ║ 2016 ║
║ 11 ║   7    ║ 2016 ║
----------------------
```

**Table-03: bid_2015**

After calling bid/Tender, rate of the corresponding companies for selected items are stored in this table. Each company will not give bid price for each items selected for a particular year. Tables are created according to the `year` alias. Here bid rate for year 2015 are stored as below:

```
--------------------------------
║ id ║ itemid ║ company ║ rate ║
--------------------------------
║  1 ║   1    ║   X     ║  2.0 ║
║  2 ║   2    ║   X     ║  2.2 ║
║  3 ║   3    ║   X     ║  1.0 ║
║  4 ║   4    ║   X     ║ 10.0 ║
║  5 ║   5    ║   X     ║ 15.0 ║
║  6 ║   1    ║   Y     ║  1.5 ║
║  8 ║   2    ║   Y     ║  2.0 ║
║  9 ║   3    ║   Y     ║  1.5 ║
║ 10 ║   4    ║   Y     ║ 12.0 ║
║ 11 ║   6    ║   Y     ║ 20.0 ║
--------------------------------
```

I need a html table (with input field) for data entry/edit for a particular year (Here, for 2015). Table will contain following:

1) Table will show each items for `clothing catagory (catid-2)`those are declared for the bid/tender for 2015.

2) If a company bids price, price will be in rate column, otherwise rate column will be blank. Administrator can either change the price (if entered wrong bid price) or add rate for other items which was not entered at first for a particular table.

So the look of the html table form will be as below:

```
HTML Form-Table (For Data Entry/Edit) : For Company-Y and clothing catagory for the year-2015

Company: (drop-down menu- Company-Y)
------------------------------------------------------
  Item Name |  Rate  |
----------------------
   Pant     | 12.0   |         
-----------------------
   Shirt    |          
-----------------------
    Coat    | 20.0    |          
-----------------------
      ============
         Submit
      ============
```

As you can see Rate of Shirt is blank for Company-Y as this company did not give bid price for Shirt. If this company give the price of Shirt at later, rate can be entered and can update the table.

So what would be mysql query to get a html form table like above?
If I execute this query:

```
SELECT i.itemname,d.rate FROM table_item as i INNER JOIN bid_item as b ON i.itemid=b.itemid LEFT JOIN bid_2015 as d ON b.itemid=d.itemid WHERE i.catid=2 AND d.company='Y' AND b.year=2015
```

But the expected html table is not coming. As INNER and LEFT Join are used, `Item Name`s are shown more than once in the form table.

What will be the effective mysql query to output a html form table like above?

Comment: @dan08, I can fetch the mysql query result to create a html form using html and css. I don't need that. I need only mysql query.

Comment: oh ok, thats not how i read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

this works for all data of company Y in 2015

```
select itemname,
      rate 
from table_item join bid_item on(table_item.itemid=bid_item.itemid and year=2015 and catid=2) 
left join bid_2015 on( bid_2015.itemid=bid_item.itemid and
  bid_item.itemid=table_item.itemid and company='Y' and year=2015 and catid=2)
```

Comment: No, I think it will return items those price are given by company-Y in 2015. But there are still item `Shirt` which price is not given by company-Y. Also, you have to filter category `Clothing` only (`Writing` category items will not be in html form table)

Comment: Adarsh Mohan > this works for all data of company Y in 2015...........No, I don't need all data of company Y, I need `clothing` category items of company Y in 2015

Comment: wait. let me try for another solution

Comment: Adarsh Mohan, it will be my pleasure if you create a sql fiddle for me and test the above table and code. I know it will be a time consuming work to create a fiddle, but it will help me lot to see the result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both of you (Adarsh Mohan and Subin C Poonamgode) are great and both of your code work great. If I could, I accepted both of your answer. But as stackoverflow permits me to select one answer as accepted, I have decided to accept Adarsh Mohan's answer because reputation of Adarsh Mohan is comparatively lower than Subin. My acceptance will help him increasing his reputation. On the other hand, Subin's has comparatively higher reputation, I think he is well enough to show his competency. Hope Subin will not mind, he will take it easy. Anyway, I will vote up for both of you. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

This query will work fine.

```
SELECT i.itemname,
d.rate 
FROM table_item as i 
INNER JOIN bid_item as b ON i.itemid=b.itemid AND b.year=2015
LEFT JOIN bid_2015 as d ON b.itemid=d.itemid AND d.company='Y'
WHERE i.catid=2
```

---

> **Note:**
>
> > When ever you are making `LEFT/RIGHT joins` on a table (say `b` as in
> >     your example below). Never put conditions of `table 'b'` in `WHERE`
> >     clause. It will act as `INNER JOIN` .
>
> So the this code
>
> ```
>  SELECT i.itemname,
>         d.rate 
>    FROM table_item as i 
>    INNER JOIN bid_item as b ON i.itemid=b.itemid 
>    LEFT JOIN bid_2015 as d ON b.itemid=d.itemid 
>   WHERE i.catid=2 AND d.company='Y' AND b.year=2015
> ```
>
> Act as `INNER JOIN` as given below.
>
> ```
> SELECT i.itemname,
>             d.rate 
>        FROM table_item as i 
>        INNER JOIN bid_item as b ON i.itemid=b.itemid 
>        INNER JOIN bid_2015 as d ON b.itemid=d.itemid 
>       WHERE i.catid=2 AND d.company='Y' AND b.year=2015
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Subin, It is 12:30 AM at our country. I will check your code tomorrow and let you know the result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here it is 12.00 am in INdia

Comment: Yes, I am from Bangladesh. Our time is 30 min ahead from your country time.

Comment: Both of you (Adarsh Mohan and Subin C Poonamgode) are great and both of your code work great. If I could, I accepted both of your answer. But as stackoverflow permits me to select one answer as accepted, I have decided to accept Adarsh Mohan's answer because reputation of Adarsh Mohan is comparatively lower than Subin. My acceptance will help him increasing his reputation. On the other hand, Subin's has comparatively higher reputation, I think he is well enough to show his competency. Hope Subin will not mind, he will take it easy. Anyway, I will vote up for both of you. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your note. It is a great learning for me.